# what is the use of defined('APPLICATION_PATH') in index.php file?

Tags: zend-framework

i am novice to Zend framework so asking a basic question that i cannot find out the use of the defined('APPLICATION_PATH') in index.php as this file loads firstly so APPLICATION_PATH has to be defined here and only here..

```
// Define path to application directory

defined('APPLICATION_PATH')
    || define('APPLICATION_PATH', realpath(dirname(__FILE__) . '/application'));
```

Answer (score 0):

APPLICATION_PATH is the global constant which defines the absolute path in file system to your Zend Framework application.

**EDIT:** This constant can be already predefined in *htaccess* file.

Comment: this is not my question
 i know its the global constant and if it has to be defined in index.php then why defined funtion is used with it.. useless??

Answer (score 0):

[defined](http://php.net/manual/en/function.defined.php), is a boolean.

This line checks if `'APPLICATION_PATH'` exists and isset, if not the rest of the line will define the constant.

```
//if APPLICATION_PATH is not set then define the APPLICATION_PATH
defined('APPLICATION_PATH')
     or define('APPLICATION_PATH', realpath(dirname(__FILE__) . '/application'));
```

This allows for instances where an external config file of some sort (xml, .htaccess ...) maybe required to setup the application space.